# Adding custom validators dynamically

Tags: validation, jsf, facelets

Here is the pseudo code of what I'd like to achive:

```
<h:inputText id="inputId">
    for -> validatorId : validatorIdArray 
     {
          <f:validator for="inputId" validatorId="#{validatorId}"/>
     }
</h:inputText>
```

I'd like to add custom validators to my input component dynamically. I have the validator names stored in an array or List, but so far I haven't managed to figure it out how to generate the validator tags.

Preferrably I'd like to have a full Facelets solution.

Comment: couldnt you have one uber validator that calls the wanted validator using reflexion? ofc u dont get anything in xhtml then :(

Comment: I solved it as mentioned in my answer. BUT. I see the point of your answer, and I like it. I could actually use the UIComponent to determine the type and then delegate according to this info to a specific validator. Might be useful as well!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use `<c:foreach>` first but with the wrong namespace.
Now that I corrected it, it works as expected:

```html
<h:inputText id="inputId">
    <c:forEach items="#{validatorIdArray}" var="validatorId">
        <f:validator for="inputId" validatorId="#{validatorId}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score -1):

try f:validateBean if you are using JSF2

Comment: The thing is that the names of the validators are stored in DB. So should I annotate all my entities with all possible validation groups?